# google analytics not recording transactions

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Im seeing visitors, page request, etc, but no transactions/conversions are appearing in google analytics. It was working recently but since my last code push it hasn't recorded a transaction (even though there have been many in that time).

I have trawled through my change list but can't see anything which could cause this to happen, and my dataLayer code seems to be in order.

I've enabled previewing in Google Tag Manager and this is the output:

[image]

I can also see the following request in Google Tag Assistant Chrome Extension, so it looks like the trigger is firing:

```
www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1
&_v=j41
&a=370988122
&t=transaction
&_s=1
&dl=http%3A%2F%2Fblah.com%2Fcheckout%2Fppexp%2Fpayment
&ul=en-us
&de=UTF-8
&dt=ACME%20Checkout
&sd=24-bit
&sr=2560x1440
&vp=2543x948
&je=0
&fl=20.0%20r0
&_u=SCCAAAATI~
&jid=
&cid=1209500833.1453740341
&tid=UA-XXXXXXXX-X
&gtm=GTM-XXXXXX
&ti=1135114249
&ta=ACME
&tr=27.09
&ts=3.09
&tt=4.51
&z=602872780

www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1
&_v=j41
&a=370988122
&t=item
&_s=2
&dl=http%3A%2F%2Fblah.com%2Fcheckout%2Fppexp%2Fpayment
&ul=en-us
&de=UTF-8
&dt=ACME%20Checkout
&sd=24-bit
&sr=2560x1440
&vp=2543x948
&je=0
&fl=20.0%20r0
&_u=SCCAAAATI~
&jid=
&cid=1209500833.1453740341
&tid=UA-XXXXXXXX-X&
gtm=GTM-XXXXXX
&ti=1135114249
&ic=Art%20Nouveau
&in=Art%20Print%20Size%20Small%20Poster
&iv=Art%20Print
&ip=24
&iq=1
&z=35031258
```

Any suggestions as to how to proceed?

Comment: Make sure you wait at least 24 hours before checking your reports, and also ensure ecommerce tracking is enabled and that you have no filters blocking transactions somehow. But the hit details look good though.

Comment: Tracking call is okay - you can check by inserting /debug/ (i.e. https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect?v=1....) into the tracking url and paste in to the adress bar - this will check if your hit is valid (it is). Maybe somebody accidentally switched on enhanced ecommerce in the view settings ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As nyuen suggested, I waited 24 hours and my transactions started to appear.

The underlying issue was that my triggers had been changed and it took google analytics a bit of time to start recording transactions under the new triggers.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you code doesn't match the standard purchase snippet and usually causes transactions to be received and not processed.

Try update your code to match:

https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#purchases

```
<script>
// Send transaction data with a pageview if available
// when the page loads. Otherwise, use an event when the transaction
// data becomes available.
dataLayer.push({
  'ecommerce': {
    'purchase': {
      'actionField': {
        'id': 'T12345',                         // Transaction ID. Required for purchases and refunds.
        'affiliation': 'Online Store',
        'revenue': '35.43',                     // Total transaction value (incl. tax and shipping)
        'tax':'4.90',
        'shipping': '5.99',
        'coupon': 'SUMMER_SALE'
      },
      'products': [{                            // List of productFieldObjects.
        'name': 'Triblend Android T-Shirt',     // Name or ID is required.
        'id': '12345',
        'price': '15.25',
        'brand': 'Google',
        'category': 'Apparel',
        'variant': 'Gray',
        'quantity': 1,
        'coupon': ''                            // Optional fields may be omitted or set to empty string.
       },
       {
        'name': 'Donut Friday Scented T-Shirt',
        'id': '67890',
        'price': '33.75',
        'brand': 'Google',
        'category': 'Apparel',
        'variant': 'Black',
        'quantity': 1
       }]
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Pay special attention to the numbers and ensure that quantity is the only element that isn't in quotation.  Transaction id, product id, shipping tax, etc are all included in single quotes.

Comment: The link you refer to is for enhanced ecommerce, which has a slightly different specification.